# Book about a boy who is a lab experiment, has some ESP or is just super smart, and has a female caretaker/trainer

Tags: story-identification, books

There's this book I read a while ago that I just can't remember the name of. What I can remember is that it's in the far future, it's about a boy who is a lab experiment. He either has some ESP or is just super smart. He has a female caretaker/trainer who works with him and whom he likes. And then there is a second boy who joins him in the experiment and who he is jealous of and competes with to get the caretaker's attention.

Answer (score 3):

For some reason I feel that you're thinking of [*Ender's Shadow*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?19937) (1999) by Orson Scott Card.  It is a parallel novel, in part, to *Ender's Game* that follows Bean instead of Ender.

The story starts with Bean surviving alone on the streets of Amsterdam by joining, and then helping mastermind, a gang until he comes to the attention of Sister Carlotta, who is looking for intelligent street kids to sent to the International Fleet to give them a better chance in life.  Sister Carlotta becomes his protector and parental figure, and Bean becomes very attached to her.

Bean meets your point of being an experiment; he is the sole survivor of a group of babies illegally genetically engineered by a rogue scientist named Volescu.  He is incredibly intelligent; as a six-month-old baby he is capable of escaping from the lab, and he understands psychology enough to manipulate children and adults as a five-year-old.

His rival, in the street and later in Battle School is a dangerous psychopath named Achilles.  Bean isn't jealous of Achilles, but Achilles *is* jealous of Bean, and works to always take a greater share of anything than Bean.